# Nothing happen when run a script when a trigger an action from AppSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-appsheet

I followed this guide, to rename file in Google Drive when a trigger an action from AppSheet, but Google Drive file names don't change:

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Tips-Tricks/How-to-control-or-rename-uploaded-files-in-a-fil...

This is the last execution, apparently there are no errors

But it should change the file names in Google Drive.

see image attached.

**And this is my custom code:
**

```
function renameFile(coec_cedula, coec_nombres,  coec_apellidos) {
  //Log Request
  console.log(`Received request for ${coec_cedula} with Cheque No ${coec_nombres} and amount of ${coec_apellidos}`);

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1qP-Jv7OWxTlLCaxH9HpFmQC7R20Ew6bm"); 
  let subfolder = folder.getFoldersByName(coec_cedula);
  
   
  if(subfolder.hasNext()) {
    let subfolderObj = subfolder.next();
    let subfolderId = subfolderObj.getId();
    
    // Get the folder id of the subfolder created via the [FILE] column's Image/File Path
    let coec_cedulaFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(subfolderId);
    
    // Get all the files inside the folder
    let files = coec_cedulaFolder.getFiles();
    let file;

    // Loop through each file in the folder
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      file = files.next();
      filename = file.getName();
      
      if (filename.includes( coec_nombres )) {

        // get the file extension of the uplaoded file
        let ext = filename.split(".").pop();

        console.log( filename );
        // Rename the file
        let newName = `${coec_cedula}.${ext}`;
        
        //Rename the file in Google Drive
        file.setName(newName);
        
        let newValue = `/CWA_OEC_ApprovedData_Files/${coec_cedula}/${newName}`;
        
        return newValue;  // Return the new value to AppSheet
      } 
            
    }  // while files.hasNext()

  } // if subfolder.hasNext()
} // end function renameFile
```

[image atached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG4Xb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified it so that it figures out the real path for you but I found that the file is getting renamed properly.

```
function myFunk01(a = "folder11", b = "1", c = "1") {
  console.log(`Received request for ${a} with Cheque No ${b} and amount of ${c}`);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("gobj.globals.testid");
  let subfolder = folder.getFoldersByName(a);
  if (subfolder.hasNext()) {
    let subfolderObj = subfolder.next();
    let fid = subfolderObj.getId();
    let cfldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
    let files = cfldr.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      let filename = file.getName();
      if (filename.includes(b)) {
        let ext = filename.split(".").pop();
        Logger.log(filename);
        let newName = `${a}.${ext}`;
        file.setName(newName);
        var pA = [];//path array 
        pA.push(file.getName());
        var fo = file.getParents();
        while (fo.hasNext()) {
          let f = fo.next();
          pA.push(f.getName());
          fo = f.getParents()
        }
        var path = pA.reverse().join(' / ');
        let newValue = path;//includes file name
        Logger.log(newValue);
        return newValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```